# Pushing back to git repo in Jenkinsfile using GIT_ASKPASS

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to push back to the repo that the Jenkins Pipeline checked out using the same process that the code was checked out with (using `GIT_ASKPASS`)?

I currently have a workaround solution for achieving this by grabbing the credentials like this:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'github', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASS', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USER')]) {
  sh('git push https://$GIT_USER:$GIT_PASS@github.com/orgname/private-repo.git master')
}
```

I'm not a Groovy developer, but found a method in the git-client-plugin that I would like to use.  Is there a way to use the following method directly in the `Jenkinsfile`

`launchCommandWithCredentials`

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-client-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gitclient/CliGitAPIImpl.java#L1649